# Word to describe an increase in technology and processes

Tags: single-word-requests, technology

I am trying to say the following:

> "The Machine Stops" is E.M. Forster’s literary attempt to call to attention to an ever-growing *technicalization* of society.

Of course, that is not a word, but I need a word or phrase that does the same job. I thought that maybe mechanization might work, but that doesn't really describe what I am trying to say, since that implies that only machines are involved, while I am thinking of machines and beyond (i.e. all technical processes).

Answer (score 1):

***Technicalization*** should work fine:

> (noun) 2. The introduction of technology
>   <sub>[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/technicalization)</sub>

Else, I think the closest you'll get is ***technologicalization***.

See Google Books examples for [*technologicalization*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22technologicalization%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), and for [*technologicalisation*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22technologicalisation%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

I can't quote them here, because these books are very old, and the pages are scanned versions.

One example from *[Challenges and Policy Programmes of China's New Leadership
edited by Joseph Y. S. CHENG](https://books.google.ae/books?id=E7ce4EPopggC&pg=PA159&dq=%22technologicalisation%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22technologicalisation%22&f=false)*

[image: Image example from Google Books]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put it like this:

> "The Machine Stops" is E.M. Forster’s literary attempt to call to attention the *ever-increasing pace of (technological) innovation* in society.

[Real-world example](http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/bill-gates-says-the-pace-of-innovation-is-as-fast-as-ever-1.2972866):

> "Bill Gates says the pace of innovation is as fast as ever"

[Wikipedia page on *pace of innovation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pace_of_innovation)

Answer (score 0):

As in:

> "The 4th Industrial Revolution calls to attention the ever-growing
>   technicalization of society."

**The Fourth Industrial Revolution** or **4IR** [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Industrial_Revolution)

> is the fourth major industrial era since the initial Industrial
>   Revolution of the 18th century. It is characterized by a fusion of
>   technologies that is blurring the lines between the physical, digital,
>   and biological spheres.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Industrial_Revolution) It is marked by emerging technology
>   breakthroughs in a number of fields, including robotics, artificial
>   intelligence, blockchain, nanotechnology, quantum computing,
>   biotechnology, The Internet of Things, 3D printing and autonomous
>   vehicles.

And now they talk of the *5IR*! [5th Industrial Revolution](http://bigthink.com/the-voice-of-big-think/is-a-fifth-industrial-revolution-in-the-works)